# WooCommerce API: custom payment gateway form validation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, payment-gateway, payment

I would like to know how to validate a form when creating custom WooCommerce payment gateway.

This is my code:

```
public function payment_fields(){

        echo '<fieldset id="wc-' . esc_attr( $this->id ) . '-cc-form">';

        echo 
            "<div class='pb-card-form'>
                <div class='pb-card-form-top'>
                    <label for='card-number'>Credit Card Number</label>
                    <input id='pb-card-number' type='number' name='card-number'>
                </div>

                <div class='pb-card-form-bottom'>
                    <div class='pb-card-form-expiry'>
                        <label for='card-expiry'>Expiry Date</label>
                        <input id='pb-card-expiry' type='text' name='card-expiry' placeholder='MM/YY'>
                    </div>
                    <span class='pb-card-bottom-spacer'></span>
                    <div class='pb-card-form-ccv'>
                        <label for='card-ccv'>CCV</label>
                        <input id='pb-card-ccv' type='number' name='card-ccv'>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>";

        echo '</fieldset>';
    }
public function validate_fields(){
        wc_add_notice("Post: " . $_POST['card-expiry'], "error");
        return false;
    }
```

The notice outputs `Post:`  without any post data from the card expiry (even though I did enter the data)

Answer (score 0):

### **SOLVED:**

I solved this by wrapping the form in the following lines of code:

```
echo '<fieldset id="wc-' . esc_attr( $this->id ) . '-cc-form">';

        do_action("woocommerce_credit_card_form_start", $this->id); //Added this line

        echo 
            "<div class='pb-card-form'>
                <div class='pb-card-form-top'>
                    <label for='card-number'>Credit Card Number</label>
                    <input id='pb-card-number' type='number' name='card-number'>
                </div>

                <div class='pb-card-form-bottom'>
                    <div class='pb-card-form-expiry'>
                        <label for='card-expiry'>Expiry Date</label>
                        <input id='pb-card-expiry' type='text' name='card-expiry' placeholder='MM/YY'>
                    </div>
                    <span class='pb-card-bottom-spacer'></span>
                    <div class='pb-card-form-ccv'>
                        <label for='card-ccv'>CCV</label>
                        <input id='pb-card-ccv' type='number' name='card-ccv'>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>";

        do_action("woocommerce_credit_card_form_end", $this->id); //And this line

        echo '</fieldset>';
```

After this I was able to retrieve the POSTed data.